# Map country coordinates to screen pixels on hold

Tags: algorithm, math, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have the coordinates of three cities in Latvia

57.4093885,21.5246563

56.9713962,23.9890814

55.8958226,26.4671762

I need to place them on my map of Latvia. I can not understand the algorithm as it is placed on my map. What algorithm can I use to translate my latitude and longitude into points on my map.

[my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWTiE.png)

Comment: You have to get familiar with different map projections.

Comment: im use Mercator map

Answer (score 0):

For Merkator projection mapping is rather simple.

Map has bounding coorinates - `LatMin, LonMin, Lattin, LonMax`. It corresponds to screen rectangle with coordinates 0, 0, Width, Height.

Longitude has linear mapping

```
X = Width * (Lon - LonMin) / (LonMax- LonMin)
```

Latitude should be calculated [with some math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Generalization_to_the_ellipsoid):

```
 a = 6378137    //geo-ellipsoid parameters
 b = 6356752.31
 f=(a-b)/a
 e=sqrt(2*f-f^2)  //excentricitet
 YY = a * ln(Tan(pi / 4 + Lat / 2) * 
     ((1 - e * sin(Lat)) / (1 + e * sin(Lat)))**(e/2));
```

Simpler, less exact version:

```
 YY = a * ln(Tan(pi / 4 + Lat / 2))
```

Find YY for LatMin, for LatMax, for city latitude Lat and apply similar linear interpolation

```
 Y = Height * (YY_Lat - YY_LonMin) / (YY_LonMax- YY_LonMin)
```

Comment: Сenter of Latvia 56.946285, 24.105078. Can I build on this data? What do you have in mind? Can show an example with real data?

Comment: I rechecked latitude calculation and gave formulas

Comment: Сenter of Latvia is not sufficient, you need two points to determine scale

Comment: I do not understand what data exactly. Can you show me an example with a map of Latvia?

Comment: Have you got bounding coordinates for your map?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_extreme_points_of_Latvia  Note - these points are important only if Latvia's map is exactly inscribed in screen rectangle.